# Replacing data on terraform foreach while reading sops

Tags: terraform

This i think is a good one :)

I am reading a YAML sops file, which terraform changes the indentation for `.`, and using this sops file to create vault resources.

This is the piece of tf code:

```
data "sops_file" "account_secrets" {
  source_file = "${path.module}/secrets/secrets.yaml"
  input_type  = "yaml"
}


resource "vault_kv_secret_v2" "secrets" {
  for_each = nonsensitive(data.sops_file.secrets.data)
  mount    = "test"
  name     = each.key
  cas      = 1
  data_json = jsonencode(
    {
      (each.key) = (each.value),
    }
  )


  custom_metadata {
    max_versions = 5 #var.max_versions != "" ? 5 : var.max_versions
  }
}
```

While, the sops file has this structure, which is totally random (doesnt follow any kind of structure)

```
AAAAA:
    AAAAAAAAA: SECRET
    BBBBBBBBB: SECRET
    CCCCCCCCC: SECRET
    DDDDDDDDD: SECRET
BBBBB:
    EEEEEEEEE:
        FFFFFFFFF: SECRET
CCCC:
    DDDDD:
        EEEEEE:
            FFFFFF:
                DDDDDD: SECRET
                IIIIIII: SECRET
    IIIIIIII:
        RRRRRRRR: SECRET
    UUUUUUU:
        OOOOOOOO: SECRET
        RRRRRRRR: SECRET
...
```

So far is, i am getting the values like this:

```
# vault_kv_secret_v2.secrets["ccccc.ddddddd.eeeeeee.ffffffff.dddddddd.iiiiii"] will be created
  + resource "vault_kv_secret_v2" "secrets" {
      + cas                 = 1
      + data                = (sensitive value)
      + data_json           = (sensitive value)
      + delete_all_versions = false
      + disable_read        = false
      + id                  = (known after apply)
      + metadata            = (known after apply)
      + mount               = "test"
      + name                = "ccccc.ddddddd.eeeeeee.ffffffff.dddddddd.iiiiii"
      + path                = (known after apply)

      + custom_metadata {
          + max_versions = 5
        }
    }
```

- name > This is not optimal for vault, because vault needs `/` to put the secrets in somewhat subfolders.
- data_json > Secret is pulled correctly and in the `data_json.(each.value)` the secret is ok but on the data_json.(each.key) is again like `name` (aaaa.bbbb....)

I tried do in the code, something like this using `replace`, `split`, `element`, etc:

```
data_json = jsonencode(
    {
      replace("/", each.key) = (each.value),
    }
  )
```

...but it told me that `str` is needed.

Ideas? suggestions?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `replace` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/replace) requires three arguments:

- The starting string to make the replacements in.
- The substring to search for.
- The substring to replace any matches with.

Your call to `replace` has only two arguments, so Terraform is correct to complain that there is a missing argument.

If I'm understanding correctly your goal, I think the correct call would be:

```
replace(each.key, ".", "/")
```

This would then replace all of the dots in `each.key` with slashes, leaving all of the other characters unchanged.

For example, `ccccc.ddddddd.eeeeeee.ffffffff.dddddddd.iiiiii` would become `ccccc/ddddddd/eeeeeee/ffffffff/dddddddd/iiiiii`.

Comment: Man, i was so tired i didnt saw it.